# What is Immediate Invoke in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

What is this round-bracket thing inside the curly braces ?

```
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => (
        <h1>The Header</h1>
      ))()}
    </div>
  );
}
export default ImmediateInvoke;
```

Comment: You mean what is it, literally, or what's the purpose? Literally, it's the immediate function expression, same in react as everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and this is not a React feature. Just plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a function and immediately call it. Useful in cases where you need to wrap a piece of code instead of writing this code in a global context, and automatically use it. In your case, an anonymous function is being created and called right after. If you wanted to save the function that you are calling, then declaration would need to happen first.

```
var myFunction = function() {
  console.log('Exextuing myFunction...');
};
myFunction();
```

This way you could also reuse it later if you wanted to.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('`

Comment: Nice catch! I rewrote it.

Comment: It works now, but `myFunction` doesn't seem to be a good name as this variable doesn't reference a function. It's `undefined` to be precise.

Comment: You're right. It was assigning a call to that variable and not the function itself.